# What is the correct way to add a utility module to a CPAN distribution?

Tags: perl, cpan

I would like to factor out some of the stuff in [Crypt::SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay)'s `Makefile.PL` into a couple of separate classes. These classes would only be used by `Makefile.PL`. As such, I do want them

1. not to be indexed by the PAUSE indexer
2. not to be installed as part of the module.

Should I just put them in `inc` the way [Module::Install](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Install) does? What else should I pay attention to?

Comment: This sounds like an ideal time to convert to Dist::Zilla and then put your new functionality into a dzil plugin.

Comment: @Ether *Sigh* you are right. Sadly, I feel I may never *understand* `Dist::Zilla` much less use it properly.

Comment: OK, so that gave rise to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000837/where-can-i-find-a-concise-guide-to-converting-an-existing-cpan-module-to-use-dis

Comment: I don't think dzil is the solution to this problem.  It appears that you're talking about things that Makefile.PL does at install time.  Dist::Zilla plugins operate at tarball-creation time.  (I still recommend using dzil for other benefits, but this isn't the problem it's trying to solve.)

Comment: @cjm I realized that and updated my other question. Is there a way to generate a `Makefile.PL` using `Dist::Zilla` that will include the requisite install time functionality?

Comment: There are really two questions here: how to fake out the PAUSE indexer and how to not install other modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PAUSE looks for a `no_index` parameter in the META.yml file (specifications: [v1.4](http://module-build.sourceforge.net/META-spec-current.html), [v2](http://p3rl.org/CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aSpec)). The default META.yml that `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` makes contains

```
no_index:
    directory:
        - t
        - inc
```

but you can add more data to it if you'd like

```
    package:
        - Some::Package::Used::For::Building::But::Not::To::Be::Installed
    file:
        - a-file/with/a/package/statement/that-should-be/ignored.pm
```

Answer (score 2):

There are really two issues here. One is to prevent PAUSE from indexing the extra modules in your distribution so they don't show up in the *02packages*, and how not to fool a user into installing them.

The PAUSE answer is a combination of the proper fix, the `no_index` stuff, and the old folklore of faking out *mldistwatch*. PAUSE wants to discover which packages are in your distro. It looks for the [package](http://perldoc.perl.org/dist/package.html) on the same line as a namespace. If it's not on the same line, PAUSE passes over it. So, you'll see in some older "hidden" modules lines like:

```
 package # separate lines get past PAUSE
      Some::Helper::Module;
```

If you like looking behind the curtain, the relevant code is in [PAUSE::mldistwatch::filter_pms()](http://github.com/andk/pause/blob/master/lib/PAUSE/mldistwatch.pm) in (the [PAUSE github repo](http://github.com/andk/pause)).

The other problem is to not install extra things that are in the distro. Indexing has nothing to do with that. Build files move a lot of stuff into *blib* (the build library) to prepare them for installation. Anything ending up in there gets installed. The trick is to not let the builder put your helper modules in there. That's usually not a problem as long as you don't put them at the top level of your distro or in the *lib* directory.